# Communication through USB to an STM32F4 microcontroller delay

Tags: c#, c, serial-port, usb, stm32f4

I am working on a C# development project which aims at controlling a flying robot thanks to a set of Optitrack cameras (infrared Motion capture system). The concept works really well, you get a position from the camera system, our application can access to these data and we can control the robot.

The problem comes, I believe, from the communication chain. We have a USB cable linking our PC to an STM32F4 based board, which acts as a bridge and simply sends everything received on USB to radio thanks to an embedded NRF module (nRF24L01+ chip). This mechanic goes both way (NRF -> USB -> PC). The board is running under C using FreeRTOS. The PC runs Windows 10.

On the PC side we use the official STM32 VCP driver 1.4 from ST. On the board firmware, we have this user-made library for VCP on STM32F4: https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/08/library-24-virtual-com-port-vcp-stm32f4xx/
There are no queues on the bridge board except the ones from the radio module itself and potentially the STM32 VCP driver itself. I checked, there is a circular buffer in this driver used for in and out messages. Using JSCOPE I can visualize in real time how this circular buffer behaves and I've never seen an overflow happening.

My problem comes from the fact that a delay suddenly appears.
The system works perfectly for tens of minutes (between 10 to 20 minutes) and then a delay is clearly perceptible, which makes the controller oscillate. This happens when I do a second flight.

The following have been tried:
- Restart the C# application
- Run the C# application in debug mode and stand alone mode
- Change USB cable (shorter)
- Change USB port
- Change of computer
- Reinstall the ST VCP drivers
- Lower drastically the communication frequency (the control loop)

When the problem appears, the above solutions didn't work, the delay remains completely and none of the above proved to make it more reliable.

On the C# application, I reset all communication Lists before each flight. The SerialPort port object (from System.IO) has its buffers reset as well (DiscardOutBuffer, DiscardInBuffer, BaseStream.Flush methods)

I found a "hack" to make it work, but it is not what we want as a final solution. The "hack" is to simply physically disconnect / reconnect the USB connecting the board acting as a bridge. After this manipulation, the delay disappears.

So my questions are:

- What could possibly bring this delay, knowing it doesn't look to be application dependant, nor frequency related (bandwidth).
- What could explain why this disappear when unplugging/plugging the bridge board ?

I know this question is about a big project and could be hard to understand from outside. Feel free to ask me for more details if needed.

Cheers,

Marc

Comment: Does reconnecting the usb also cause a Power-on reset on the bridge board?

Comment: The best option is to now get the USB bus trace. That will tell you exactly what is happening in USB bus. You can try using USBLyzer. Also where is the delay you are seeing? Is it between USB packets from board to PC?

Comment: USBLyzer is software analyzer. If you have hardware analyzer then that will be best.

Comment: C and C# are two different language, only one of these two should be tagged.

Comment: @Lanting: Yes it does.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. I never tried USBLyzer, will do. The botteleneck is not identified yet in this project (where the delay appears), but it perceptible even in manual control (using an Xbox controller sending commands through the same chain,in the same format).

I know C and C# are different languages, but this project uses both and since Firmware and high level application code interacts, it made sense to me.

Comment: Is it possible for you to (soft) reset just the nRF24L01 module? This way we could also exclude that part of the pipeline.

Comment: @Lanting: not for now. But I can change the Firmware code. Like the suggestion, I didn't think of it. I'll keep you updated

Comment: @Lanting: Ok, I reset the NRF module before each flight now. Unfortunately it didn't do the trick. I'm open to suggestion, even though I might look to see if I can soft reset or re initialize the Serial USB on the board.